# Errors installing the latest version of HPLIP

Tags: printing, hp, 17.10, hplip

When I try to install the latest HPLIP (the one of their website, which is the very latest, i.e. version 3.17.11) on my Ubuntu 17.10, everything goes fine, apart from those two errors:

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:127: RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK set_interactive(1)
```

What do they mean? How could I solve since this leads to the error of "No System Tray"? I found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/1714659), but it's not helping…

Comment: perhaps you contact HP through their hplip site; and suggest they check out 3.17.10 against Ubuntu 17.10 which is a brand-new package; and will only be supported for a matter of months; they are already working on 18.04 the LTS version whose focus is stability

Comment: @pdc Latest is 3.17.11, not 3.17.10, and they say Ubuntu 17.10 is supported as of 3.17.11

Comment: isn't that marvellous news?

Comment: @pdc, version 3.17.11 is exactly the one which gave me the issues mentioned in the question, 3.17.10 completely refused to install, saying that's incompatible with Ubuntu 17.10